# How to fix error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got - Error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router".

I've read all the similar topics. Tryed different variants, but can't find solution. I still don't have enough knowledge to understand the subject. Plz help to fix this error if you know how.

index.js

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import { store, history} from './store';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import App from './components/App/App';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} context={ReactReduxContext}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

part of reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

export default combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer
});
```

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware } from './middleware';
import reducer from './reducers/reducers';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const getMiddleware = () => applyMiddleware(
    routerMiddleware(history), promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware, createLogger()
);

export const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    getMiddleware(),
);
```

tryed do like this:
in store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware } from './middleware';
import reducer from './reducers/reducers';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const myRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const getMiddleware = () => applyMiddleware(
    myRouterMiddleware, promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware, createLogger()
);

export const store = createStore(
    reducer(history),
    getMiddleware()
);
```

in reducers.js

```
import authorization from './authorization';
import mainstate from './mainstate';
import home from './home';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

export default (history) => combineReducers({
    authorization,
    mainstate,
    home,
    router: connectRouter(history)
});
```

got the same error :(

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

`createStore(reducer, getMiddleware())` - the enhancer (middleware) needs to be the third argument, the second argument should be the store's initial state. See [the docs here](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore).

Try this instead

```
createStore(reducer, {}, getMiddleware())
```

---

The other issue is the version of the `history` package, with `react-router-dom` v5 you need to use `history` v4 (the latest version of which is `4.10.1`) - `history` v5 is only compatible with `react-router-dom` v6.

In the Codesandbox you posted in your comment below, changing the following in `package.json` makes it work

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "history": "^5.0.0", -> "history": "4.10.1",
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you! tried to do correct imports from 'connected-react-router', but still same error. I added more code from my reducers.js and store.js files may be it shows where I got the error.

Comment: Ah, wait, I think I spotted the potential issue :-) will update answer

Comment: done it ```createStore(reducer, {}, getMiddleware())``` but nothing changed, i made copy on codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-silence-t11h6?file=/src/index.js its not working project, and got a lot to do, but im total stuck at this error :/

Comment: Got it - it's a versioning issue with `history` and `react-router-dom`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of solutions out there are pointing at `history` library version.

The version `5.x` of the `history` package is causing the issues as above.

Could you please try downgrading the `history` version to `4.10.1` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62811656/13907595)